# Auto select all files from folder with filters (alternative for not using Application.GetOpenFileName)

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a code that selects multiple '.csv' files by Application.GetOpenFilename for later importing of these files, but I'd like for all the files in a specific folder to be automatically selected without the user needing to manually selecting them.

This is the section that I'm interested in improving. And below the full code in case something else needs to change.

```
ChDrive "Q"
ChDir "Q:\TEST\Reports CSV\"
myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)
```

Full code:

```
Sub ImportMultipleCSV()
Dim myfiles
Dim i As Integer
Dim xSht  As Worksheet
Dim ReportsDate As String
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import Data").Range("A3:AV100").ClearContents
With Application
.DisplayAlerts = False
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With
ChDrive "Q"
ChDir "Q:\TEST\Reports CSV\"
myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)
'Import multiple csv in semicolon delimitation
If IsArray(myfiles) Then
  For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
    .Name = "Sample"
    .FieldNames = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
Next i
Else
MsgBox "No File Selected"
End If
Dim xConnect As Object
   For Each xConnect In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
      If xConnect.Name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then xConnect.Delete
Next xConnect
With Application
.DisplayAlerts = True
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Dir function to automatically retrieve all of your CSV files from your folder.  Accordingly, your code could be re-written as follows...

```
Sub ImportMultipleCSV()
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import Data")

    destWS.Range("A3:AV100").ClearContents
    
    Dim fileCount As Long
    fileCount = 0
    
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = "C:\Users\Domenic\Desktop\" 'change the path accordingly
    If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        myPath = myPath & "\"
    End If
    
    'get the first CSV file from the folder
    Dim myFile As String
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    
    'loop through each CSV in the folder
    While Len(myFile) > 0
        'Import multiple csv in semicolon delimitation
        With destWS.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
          "TEXT;" & myPath & myFile, Destination:=destWS.Range("A" & destWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            .Name = myFile
            .FieldNames = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SaveData = True
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 2
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        fileCount = fileCount + 1
        myFile = Dir 'get the next CSV from the folder
    Wend
    
    If fileCount > 0 Then
        Dim xConnect As Object
        For Each xConnect In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
            If xConnect.Name <> "ThisWorkbookDataModel" Then xConnect.Delete
        Next xConnect
    End If
    
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Number of files processed: " & fileCount
End Sub
```

Note that if you're files are in fact delimited by a semi-colon instead of a comma, you'll need to modify the above code by replacing...

```
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
```

with

```
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works amazingly well!!

Comment: That's great, glad I could help, cheers!